# Unable to delete topics in kafka-node

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-node

I want to delete all the topics present in kafka using kafka-node but admin.deleteTopic() or admin.deleteTopic() , both are not working giving it is not defined.

I'm expecting to a js file by running that I can delete all the kafka-topics present using kafka-node V5.0.0

I'm using following code:

```
const kafka = require('kafka-node');
const client = new kafka.KafkaClient({ kafkaHost: 'localhost:9093,localhost:9094' });
const admin = new kafka.Admin(client);

    admin.listTopics((err, res) => {
       if (err) {
         console.error(err);
         return;
       }
  
        const topicsToDelete = Object.keys(res[1].metadata)

        console.log(topicsToDelete);

        admin.deleteTopics({ topics: topicsToDelete }, (err, res) => {
             if (err) {
                 console.error(err);
                 return;
             }
             console.log('Topics deleted:', res);
             });
         });
```

Comment: Please show the exact error you get

Comment: Also see https://github.com/SOHU-Co/kafka-node/issues/1445